# how to make a bounding box generate dynamically in geonames and geocoder api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder, geonames

hello I am trying to get earthquake info when user types city into map. Right now I make bounding box by hardcoding (required for geonames earthquake api). I would like to make bounding box the size of the city entered. I see in geocoder api v3 to do this:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
      }
    });
```

problem- this will not let me get north east south west which geonames needs. anyone know how?

**my current code**

```
var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                  // Calculate bounding box based on the given address
                  var north = results[0].geometry.location.lat() + .5;
                  var south = results[0].geometry.location.lat() - .5;
                  var east = results[0].geometry.location.lng() + .5;
                  var west = results[0].geometry.location.lng() - .5;

                  var earthquake = 'http://api.geonames.org/earthquakesJSON?north=' + north + '&south=' + south + '&east=' + east + '&west=' + west + '&username=*****';
```

The +5 -5 is what extends the numbers in the coordinates to create north south....etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the result[0].geometry.viewport which is a [google.maps.LatLngBounds object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds)

```
var north = results[0].geometry.viewport.getNorthEast().lat();
var south = results[0].geometry.viewport.getSouthWest().lat();
var east   = results[0].geometry.viewport.getNorthEast().lng();
var west   = results[0].geometry.viewport.getSouthWest().lng();
```

[fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8BExC/1/)

[fiddle with return message from geonames](http://jsfiddle.net/8BExC/5/)

[fiddle with hard-coded data that shows markers](http://jsfiddle.net/8BExC/6/)

Comment: I have one more question. My old code had markers for each earthquake now using latlngbounds objects they are no long there any reason why this may be ?

Comment: Don't know. What is the actual URL you are sending?  Are you getting any javascript errors? What does the code to display the earthquakes look like?

Comment: here is jsfiddle with all my javascript ....the problem is i get no errors :( http://jsfiddle.net/8BExC/

Comment: I fiddle that doesn't even attempt to execute is useless, you need to call your code to see errors.  http://jsfiddle.net/8BExC/1/

Comment: Im sorry i dont think i understand your comment can you explain?

Comment: Your fiddle didn't even attempt to run the code.  There was no HTML.  Of course you wouldn't get javascript errors.  If you look at my update, it is running into a query limit because the demo user is over quota.  Your version was encountering an error that the user didn't exist.

Comment: I have html but did not post in fiddle sorry i only made it to show you the js http://jsfiddle.net/8BExC/3/

Comment: I figured as much.  But that wasn't helpful.

Comment: will you still help me please? :) im sorry I added the html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43638/discussion-between-naomi-k-and-geocodezip)

Comment: What about the message from the geonames API is unclear?  If you are using your real username from your real server, you shouldn't get that.  [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8BExC/5/) makes the message more obvious.